# opendolphin ClientInitializationException error

Tags: javafx-8, opendolphin, dolphin-platform

I'm testing OpenDolphin and i managed to simple create server side, shared side model.

OpenDolphin version: **0.8.4**

For client side i have JavaFX application.
I made login panel with :

- ChoiceBox that loads available servers from local file
- username field
- password field
- button

Parameters for ClientConfiguration are:

- `String` urlEndpoint
- `UiThreadHandler`(uiThreadHandler the ui thread handler)

*//Creates a configuration for the Dolphin Platform. 
//urlendpoint is taken from ChoiceBox  like ("http://localhost:8080/dolphin")*

`ClientConfiguration config = new ClientConfiguration(urlEndpoint,Runnable::run);
ClientContextFactory.connect(config).get();`

if I use `Runnable::run` then client connects, but if I use `Platform::runLater` 
(the way `JavaFXConfiguration(urlEndpoint)` implements it)
I get error:

`Exception in thread "pool-2-thread-1" com.canoo.dolphin.client.ClientInitializationException: com.canoo.dolphin.client.ClientInitializationException: Can not connect to server!`

Any clue why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not found this question until now since the "Dolphin Platform" tag was missing.

In the current version of the Dolphin Platform you can simply use the "DolphinPlatformApplication" class to create your application.

You can find an example here:
https://github.com/canoo/dolphin-platform/tree/master/platform-examples/todo-example

Main Class: https://github.com/canoo/dolphin-platform/blob/master/platform-examples/todo-example/todo-client/src/main/java/com/canoo/dolphin/todo/client/ToDoClient.java

Comment: Yes, I used version 0.8.5 new features and I managed to finish my little project.